# How to implement OAuth for my website one and use it for website two

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, oauth-provider, openid-provider

I want to implement OAuth/OpenID for **Website One** and use it in **Website Two**.

I create Sign Up, Sign In, Sign Out, Profile functionality/Pages for **Website One** and want to use authentication in **Website Two** like Facebook or Twitter authentication.

As an additional information if you got interest you can visit trial websites of [**Website One**](http://tiksn.somee.com/) and [**Website Two**](http://stoze.somee.com/). Please do not expect full or correct functionality because as I said above they are just trials yet.

**P.S.**
I decided to use OAuth. Forget about OpenID.

Comment: just to be clear, you want the users to create account on website one complete with username and password and then use it on website 2 to login ?

Comment: Exactly! I want to use TIKSN ID as an OAuth for STOZE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your sites. It's not working this way.

You want STOZE to use the authentication from TIKSN? Well, you have to configure STOZE as an "oAuth resource server", so it keeps the protected resources, and configured to work only with token he gets from TIKSN, which will be configured as an "oAuth identity provider".

Read a little bit about oAuth...

OpenID is a different story - then, you will have to configure TIKSN as "OpenID provider", and configure STOZE to enable it to work with OpenID providers (so TIKSN will be one of them, but you will be able to use also Google, Yahoo, etc)

Read a little bit about OpenID...

HTH

Comment: Before posting question I was not decided which way to implement but now I decided to use OAuth instead of OpenID.

Comment: both are great, but serve different purposes.